# Equivalent of charCodeAt in Objective C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, unicode

Good Morning All,

I have an Objective C question that is coming from JavaScript.  I have a piece of code that is being run in JavaScript (code that I was handed) and it is running a critical conversion method that uses the `.charCodeAt(SOME_CHARACTER)` JavaScript method to return the Unicode code associated with that specific character.

What I need to do is find the objective c method that does the same thing.  I have tried searching through the `NSString` and Unichar classes but didn't have any luck and I didn't find anything on here when I searched so I'm hoping someone could help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, simply use the `characterAtIndex:` method of NSString:

```
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

If I remember correctly, unichar is a typedef to two bytes (kind of short).

Comment: My question after looking at the NSString documentation again is will that return the Character itself or the unicode value...

I.E. will [@"Hello" characterAtIndex:0] return @"H" or the unicode code number of @"H"?

Comment: Alright, I ran a small test line and it seems like that was the correct way of getting the unicode code value!  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I must be ignoring some simple logic here, how can i get the actual character at the index i.e. @"Hello" i want @"H" for index 0???